# install(command) & cat(command) I/O redirection

Tags: shell, gnu-coreutils

Under GNU/Linux
PS1 = "$ " ; export PS1

I'd found some tip of creating file with specific permission with this command:
$ install -b -m 604 /dev/null test.php

Also the tip to create a file with I/O redirection in cat command:
$ cat > test.php << EOF

I wonder how can I combine them without actually execute it twice ?
$ install -b -m 604 /dev/null test.php ; cat > test.php << EOF

Answer (score 0):

you could use Pipes.
the letter | means pipes

i cant execute in terminal:
cat test.php | grep hello

what will happend here is that the output of cat will be the input to grep